# Do not see Windows Phone 8 Emulator from Visual Studio 2012 express for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

After installing Visual Studio 2012 express for Windows Phone 8 on my machine along with the SDK I notice that I do not have the option to Debug to a Windows Phone 8 Emulator ?

Any specific workaround or fixes to resolve this would be helpful?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue today with VS 2012 express on Windows 8.1. Then, came across this [msdn page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) page which says "_the Windows Phone 8 emulator does not work on Windows 8.1_". Installing [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Bad, the PC I am using does not support Hardware Virtualization.

I installed multiple times and finally noticed this message at Launch time.

```
This Computer does not support hardware virtualization, which means Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run on this PC.
```

[image: This Computer does not support hardware virtualization, which means Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run on this PC.]

Comment: I get the same message, but I have run 7.1 SDK and emulator with out problems at all. I'm pretty sure my machine supports virtualization. Lenovo T500 from 2010.

Comment: @MadsLaumann I think you need to change BIOS settings to make intel virtualisation.

Answer (score 3):

If others run into this, here is what I found out.

My Intel Core 2 Duo T9550, don't support SLAT, which is needed to enable Hyper-V, which is again needed to run the WP8 emulator...sigh...

You can run this Coreinfo tool to see what your CPU supports. Follow the guidance here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx#system

The Windows Phone 7.1 SDK emulator works fine on my machine btw.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone 8 Emulator runs in Hyper-V.
Hyper-V requires a processor that supports SLAT (Second Level Address Translation).

List of SLALT (EPT) Intel CPUs: http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology

So any Core2Duo does not Support Hyper-V :/

Here is a tool to test your CPU: http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/