# Using custom WP8 emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Can I use custom Windows Phone 8 Emulator in Visual Studio 2012? I've already tried to configure VM created by VS in Hyper V Manager, but when I try to run my app in emulator VS resets custom settings to default.

Comment: You mean like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579137/customize-windows-phone-8-emulator-startup-state?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts no, I want to add network adapter with custom settings for example(I've configured VM for get internet connection and its work if I run VM through Hyper V Manager, but Visual Studio runs VM with its own settings and I can't access Internet in this case)

Comment: Does your CPU support SLAT / VM ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204451/do-not-see-windows-phone-8-emulator-from-visual-studio-2012-express-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a custom emulator or customize emulator images. The most you can do is switch skins to show your the look of your favourite phone in the emulator